# Return the distribution of categorical variables as a pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that has the final column as a label, a categorical variable with values `[0, 1]`, let's call it `df['label']`. The dataframe looks like this:

```
feat1   feat2...featn   label
.       .       .       0
.       .       .       1
.       .       .       .
.       .       .       1
```

Now I need to return a Pandas Series named `sex` of length 2 with these integer values and index = `['male', 'female']`. So far I'm stuck with using the crosstab function, but can't get the Series that is required.

```
pd.crosstab(index = df['label'], columns='count')
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a sample of what your df looks like, or an image of your expected output, I'm assuming the value_counts() function may be what your looking for?

[image: Click Here to view input]

```
 import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Label_1':[0,1,1,1]})

df.Label_1.replace(to_replace=1, value='Male', inplace=True) 
df.Label_1.replace(to_replace=0, value='Female',inplace=True)


pd.DataFrame(df.Label_1.value_counts())
```

[image: Click Here to view Output]

Let me know if this is off?

Comment: This works for me. Actually, no need to cast it to DataFrame. `value_counts` function returns a Series already. Thanks.